# Kafka subject based addressing/consumption

Tags: apache-kafka

Being new to kafka we are wondering if kafka supports our use case.
We are trying to create an eventstream which includes different types of events e.g. Created,Updated,Deleted.

We have two kind of consumers

1. Which need to consume the whole stream continuously, consider an Audit consumer.
2. Selective consumer which only need to subscribe to one event type, e.g Created-> CreateConsumer, Updated -> UpdateConsumer.

Our data would is unequally divided e.g. We can have 80% of data as Created and 10% of data as Updated.

What we are wondering what's a good strategy for this? 
The additional scaling requirement based on mix data is

Run 5 instance of AuditConsumer.

Run 4 instance of CreateConsumer.

Run 1 instance of UpdateConsumer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would create a topic for each event type, and create another consumer to stream the events to the appropriate channel.

The following is slightly more complicated, and involves more topics but will allow you to create a more streamlined process.

`CreatedEvent`/`UpdatedEvent`/`DeletedEvent` are written to topic `event_input_stream`.

`AuditConsumer` consumes from `event_input_stream` with consumer group `audit`.

`EventSplitter` consumes from `event_input_stream` with consumer group `splitter`.
`EventSplitter` checks the event type and produces to one of `created_event`, `updated_event`, `deleted_event`.

`CreatedConsumer` consumes from `created_event`.

`UpdatedConsumer` consumes from `updated_event`.

`DeletedConsumer` consumes from `deleted_event`.

```
                                           /> created_event > CreatedConsumer
event > event_input_stream > EventSplitter -> updated_event > UpdatedConsumer
                                           \> deleted_event > DeletedConsumer
```

---

The problem with having all consumers reading from the same topic is that the `UpdateConsumer` will need to read all messages even though it will discard 90% of them. This effectively means to need to scale all of the consumers equally as they will actually be consuming the same amount of messages.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several strategies:

1. You can use the event type as keys in order to set the partitions and let consumers consumer from each partitions.
2. Pushing different event types in different topics. 
   "created_event" to "created_topic", "updated_event" to "updated_topic".
3. Push all events into one topic. Use Kafka stream to consume the events and filter based on the event type and do further processing.

Personally, I will prefer the 3rd one, using kafka streams to filter the events.
Regarding the scaling, you can scale to the maximum number of partitions.

Comment: yeah, its same.